# Ephemeral Diffie-Hellman generator selection

Tags: diffie-hellman, ephemeral

I need to generate a EDH group on the fly in one has not been specified in a config file. Diffie-Hellman is kind of expensive in terms of computation, so I'd like to reduce the cost if possible.

Is there any benefit to selecting a generator of 5 versus 3 or 2 in an attempt to keep the costs minimized? Is this a misguided optimization?

Related: are there any libraries that allows you to specify, for example, {2,3,5} are acceptable generators for a group? Or do you normally just specify a subgroup order? (I know OpenSSL has for example, `DH_GENERATOR_2`, but I'm not aware its a bit mask value).

Comment: Why don't you simply hardcode a default group?

Comment: When using ephemeral DH you do not have to choose fresh group parameters all the time, but only a new exponent on every key exchange.

Comment: CodesInChaos and DrLecter - there are two choices: (1) NIST/IETF group, and (2) user supplied group. If (2) is chosen but no group provided, it is generated on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any attack made much easier by using a small generator in [EDH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange), like $g=3$ or $g=5$, even $g=2$ (but I'm not accustomed to [GNFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNFS) or [index calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_calculus_algorithm)), as long as there is a single $g$ used for a given instance of other parameter(s). These generators are common, and (especially $g=2$) allow a modest but sizable performance improvement.

I would give a reference to the desired library, if I knew one. However it is not rocket science to implement for straight EDH, when the desired criteria is known. If we want a random huge $p$ and a generator $g$ among a small list of small $g>1$ such that $g$ is a generator of the group $\mathbb Z_p^*$ where the [Discrete Log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) is hard, one possibility is to generate a random prime $p$ of the desired size until $(p-1)/2$ is also prime, and for one of the desired $g$ we have $g^{(p-1)/2}\bmod p\ne1$ (notice that $g^{p-1}\bmod p=1$ holds since $p$ is prime, and $g^2\bmod p\ne1$ holds since $g\ll\sqrt p$).

There a many other criteria in use, such as those set by [RFC 2412](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2412#page-45), used by [IKE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Key_Exchange) as defined by [RFC 2409](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2409), where in addition to $p$ and $(p-1)/2$ prime, it is wanted:

- $g=2$ and $g^{(p-1)/2}\bmod p=1$ (rather than $\ne1$), for reasons [explained by poncho](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/12972/555);
- a number of top and bottom bits of $p$ are forced to 1, in order to simplify modular reduction both by classical and Montgomery arithmetic;
- the random-looking center bits of $p$ are traceable to a [nothing up my sleeves number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing_up_my_sleeve_number).

Another common set of criteria it that for [DSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm), as specified by [FIPS 186-4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf), appendix A (also good for the Finite Field Cryptography scheme of [NIST SP 800-56Ar2](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-56Ar2.pdf) and ancestors, which use DSA public key certificates in order to resist [MITM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)). That requires more complex parameter selection; in particular, a subgroup of prime order $q$ much smaller than $p$. While still not rocket science, that parameters generation process is more involved, and constrained by the standards.